# When data is called from Firebase Database, all of the data is called, not the one associated with the user

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

For some reason, when the data is called inside the collection of users, all of the data is being called.

Here is the database: [image]

Here is the code :

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct AccountView: View {
    @State var name = ""
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    //Name
                    Text("Welcome \(name)")
                        .font(.title)
                    //Update Info
                    Button {
                        update.toggle()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Update My Info")
                    }
                    .buttonStyle(GradientButtonStyle())
                    .padding()
                }
                .navigationTitle("Account")
                .onAppear(perform: {
                    downloadNameServerData()
                })
            }
           
        }
    }
    private func downloadNameServerData() {
        if !name.isEmpty { return }
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("users").document("names")
            .addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, error in
                guard let document = documentSnapshot else {
                    print("Error fetching document: \(error!)")
                    return
                }
                guard let Name = document.data() else {
                    print("Document data was empty.")
                    return
                }
                
                name = Name
                print("Current data: \(name)")
            }
    }
```

Inside the console; when I do `print(name)` it ends up printing all of the user's names that are stored inside the database. If you look at the second image, you can see that the name is "Jeff Bezos" but in the database, the name saved to that user is "Bob the Builder[image]"
It isn't that the code has any errors, it's just that all of the users' names that are saved in the database are being called upon when I just want the one that is currently logged in.

Comment: Working around the system-imposed rules by adding non-sensical text at the end of your post is a surefire way to attract downvotes. I recommend removing that text and adding an actual more meaningful explanation of what happens when you run this code, for example: when you step through this code in a debugger, which of the many functions you shared is the first one that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect this. thank you

Comment: This code ` db.collection("users").addSnapshotListener` is loading all the users. Is that not what you expect it to do? If you only want to load a single user doc, see the first code snippet here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#swift

Comment: Everything now works except for the fact that my documents are all named differently. If you look at the first screenshot, I depict that each of the collection is called "users", but as soon as you go into them, the URL I guess changes. This isn't allowing the app to read what exactally this one individual's name is. It gives me the error `Document data was empty` because there is no document called `Name`

Comment: The `Name` in your screenshot is a **field** inside a document, it is not a document itself. You can access the `Name` field by `document.data()["Name"]`.

Answer (score 1):

This code `db.collection("users").addSnapshotListener` is loading all the documents from the `users` collection.

If you only want to load a single user doc, see the first code snippet in the documentation on [getting realtime updates a single document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#swift).

---

The `Name` in your screenshot is a **field** inside a document, it is not a document itself. You can access the `Name` field by `document.data()["Name"]`.

Comment: The console is saying `Document data was empty.` even after I added the `guard let Name = document.data()?["Name"]`. I tried to put that `document.data()["Name"]` after `db.collection("users").document("Name")` but then again got the error `Reference to member 'data' cannot be resolved without a contextual type`